# Por que não estou conseguindo modificar a classe do elemento com a propriedade classList?

Tags: javascript

Estou usando a propriedade `classList` para modificar a classe do elemento, mas não acontece o resultado que eu quero, pois não modifica a classe atual para a nova.

```js
let p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");

p1.classList[0] = "new-class";

console.log(p1);
```

```html
<p id="p1" class="class1 class2 class3"></p>
```

Porém se eu tentar atribuir um valor à propriedade `classList` sem um index, todas as classes são excluídas, permanecendo apenas a nova atribuída.

```js
let p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");

p1.classList = "new-class";

console.log(p1);
```

```html
<p id="p1" class="class1 class2 class3"></p>
```

Por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o valor retornado por [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) é um [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), que apesar de ter comportamentos similares ao *array*, não compartilha sempre os mesmos comportamentos.

Um exemplo disso é realizar uma alteração de classe com base no índice. Se você fizer:

```js
element.classList[0] = 'foo';
```

A classe `foo` não será refletida, simplesmente porque não é assim que o `DOMTokenList` funciona.

Desse modo, se você quiser trabalhar com o `classList`, terá que utilizar [um dos métodos disponíveis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList#Methods).

Talvez o `replace` faça o que você precisa. O problema é que você irá trocar uma classe com base no seu **valor** antigo, e não pelo índice. Veja:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(el.classList.value);

el.classList.replace('b', 'd');

console.log(el.classList.value);
```

```html
<div class="a b c"></div>
```

Se você realmente quiser mudar uma classe pelo seu índice, é possível criar uma "gambiarra" para isso. No entanto, não recomendo fazê-la, já que `DOMTokenList` é uma "lista viva", isto é, seu valor será alterado automaticamente sempre que uma classe for alterada.

De todo modo, ficaria assim:

```js
function changeClassByIndex(element, index, newClass) {
  // Obtemos o valor da classe atual pelo índice:
  const currentClass = element.classList.item(index);
  
  // Trocamos a classe atual:
  element.classList.replace(currentClass, newClass);
}

const el = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(el.classList.value); // a b c

changeClassByIndex(el, 1, 'd');

console.log(el.classList.value); // a d c
```

```html
<div class="a b c"></div>
```

Comment: Era exatamente o que eu esperava que a propriedade `classList` se comportasse como se fosse um Array já que tem como você retornar a classe através do index sem ter que usar métodos específicos para isso.

Comment: Sim, o problema é que se você mudar um valor pelo índice, não será refletido no DOM e nem na própria `DOMTokenList`.

Comment: blz! obrigado :)

Answer (score 3):

Usando o `classList`, para trocar uma classe do elemento por ourtra, deve ser chamado o método replace, passando a classe que deve ser trocada e a nova, por exemplo:

```
p1.classList.replace("old-class", "new-class");
```

Há outras funções também, como `remove` e `toggle`, dê uma olhada na [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) para entender melhor

Comment: Sim, mas eu falo alterar a classe sem jogá-la para o final ou seja sem alterar a ordem das classes por isso eu especifiquei com o index.

Comment: Você quer trocar a classe, `foo` por `bar`, por exemplo?

Comment: Sim, mas usando a sintaxe acima sem ter que usar, por exemplo, o método `replace()`.

Comment: Não tem como fazer com a sintaxe que demonstrou, não é assim que a API funciona, se funcionasse não teria criado a pergunta

Answer (score -4):

Está faltando por o texto, ex.:

Texto

conforme abaixo:

```js
let p1 = document.querySelector("#p1");

p1.classList = "new-class";
```

```css
.class1{
  color: blue;
}
.class2{
  font-size: 12px;
}
.class3{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.new-class{
 color: red;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h3>Está faltando por o texto dentro da tag, conforme abaixo.</h3>

<p id="p1" class="class1 class2 class3">Texto</p>

<br>
<br>
<h3>A sua publicação é a mais simples e muito funcional comparado com as dezenas que eu vi até agora. Obrigado!!!!!</h3>
```

Comment: Não é isso o que ele quer, esse é o segundo exemplo dele. " *Porém se eu tentar atribuir um valor a propriedade `classList` sem um index, todas as classes são excluídas, permanecendo apenas a nova atribuída.* "